# How to reference two stylesheets

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, href

I'm new to HTML and I'm trying to href 2 things. I don't get an error, but my style.css sheet doesn't work. Any ideas?

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css; style.css">
```

Comment: Can you explain better what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do them separately:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
```